# RFB protocol error: bad desktop size 0x0

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop, apple-remote-desktop

I have enabled remote desktop in the *remote mac machine*.

Now trying to access that *remote mac machine* from *a mac laptop*.

Using vnc viewer, I am getting the following error:

*RFB protocol error: bad desktop size 0x0*

Any idea how to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I get the same error suddenly VNCing to this Mac box (from my Windows box)... It used to work and my helpdesk team doesn't know. (note: Using RealVNC)